Is it normal for secure erase of an SSD to take only a couple of seconds?
Having unsuccessfully tried to use Kingston SSD Manager (KSM) on my SA400 480GB drive, I resorted to Kingston's process for Linux that uses hdparm. Unlike KSM that could not do anything because the drive would not leave security freeze mode, hdparm showed not frozen after resuming from sleep, and its secure erase command completed successfully but only took a couple of seconds.
I originally followed the KSM user manual's requirement to delete all partitions from the drive, so it was empty when hdparm ran.
Even the output from hdparm shows:

6min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 6min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.

So 2 seconds sounds like too quick. Is something wrong?

Not familiar with SA400 but if it's a self-encrypting drive, "secure erase" just means erasing the decryption keys, which indeed should just take a second.

See also https://superuser.com/questions/1153655/is-it-normal-for-secure-erase-on-a-samsung-ssd-to-take-only-a-few-seconds and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241268/ata-secure-erase-is-too-fast

I found always so... funny these super-secure deletion things. In most cases, there is no way to recover a simple accidental deletion.

The numbers are really just some values coded in the firmware of the the drive's controller. Your vendor can really just have any number they like, and yes, in reality, you might even bump into drives that report the length required as hours, while the SECURITY ERASE UNIT command completes in a blink.
While you can see the ATA/ACS specs hints that SECURITY ERASE UNIT is supposed to be a command that triggers a overwrite with data of specific pattern, it is vastly because the feature set dates back before SSD has become a thing. Besides, practically no one can guarantee that any vendor would implement everything according to the spec anyway.
In the case of SSD, due to legit reasons like limited number of P/E cycles, pretty much no vendor has implemented SECURITY ERASE UNIT to perform actual write. Instead, i.e., the mapping between logical blocks and the actual memory behind are destroyed (which is what would also happen on at least some drive when "TRIM" is issued on the blocks).
Some people say that if transparent encryption is deployed on a drive, the command would trigger a change of the encryption key as well, but if you have actual concern regarding security and/or plausible deniability, don't assume that is the case, because other than the fact that the command / feature set has the word SECURE, it is not even remotely hinted in the spec that the command would result in that. (Certainly, you may opt to have the faith that every vendor would "stick to the convention" and/or be "reasonable".)
P.S. More importantly, the fact that the operation is fast does not necessarily imply that transparent encryption has been deployed. Nothing mandates such "causality". For all the logical blocks (i.e., addresses) to "read zero", all it takes is that the controller marks in its memory that all blocks are unmapped, and that it would "respond" for blocks that has been marked unmapped with zeroes. (Also therefore, garbage collection / memory block erase, if triggered at all, does not have to be completed synchronously before the SECURITY ERASE UNIT command "returns" either.)

Makes sense. This drive has been previously cleaned of partitions, a single partition has been created, and it was TRIMmed. That likely shortened the erase time. The time to trim was ballpark of 20-30 sec, so that is likely it.

@SuperAl Well, while the command might share some result with TRIM in your drive, it may not necessarily trigger exactly the same activities behind the scene. Besides, since ATA TRIM is limited to 4194240 blocks per command on Linux, the fact that SE is faster than a full drive TRIM could be more or less due to the lower total overhead / "round trip time". Also, since a page / erase block of an SSD would be mapped with multiple logical blocks, when it is not "known" by the controller the whole mapping table can be discarded, TRIM may result in much more complicated activities.

If the drive is encrypted (SED), it just erases the hardware key, making decryption impossible.
Most likely, the 6 min period is required by a non-encrypted drive for actually overwriting erasing plain-text information.
Technically, there‘s no way to tell for sure - even a disk looking unencrypted could actually be encrypted and securely erased in a second. To make sure you’d have to have express information by the vendor.

It is not encrypted. What is 'plain information'?

plain (text) = unencrypted

Having thought of it, 6 min is probably to erase a 100% full drive. How's that for a theory?

It's flash - you don't need to overwrite data. That is the entire point of flash as opposed to old-style NAND: flash has erase blocks that can be fully erased almost instantly.
